# Something went wrong while saving this configuration: Incorrect theme identification key when saving store theme?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I changed the site to **Single Store Mode**

It then defaults to no theme

So when trying to update the theme I get:

```
Something went wrong while saving this configuration: Incorrect theme identification key
```

Answer (score 0):

`var/generation` is not writable.

var, `app/etc` and `pub/static` should be writable by web server. 
Please check the below link

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html

Comment: It is writable as per the permissions supplied